# $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^{\frac{1}{x}}-1}{x^{\alpha}}$ values of $\alpha $ for which limit exists in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Examine if for any value $\alpha > 0$ limit in $0$ exists and is $\in \mathbb{R}$.

$$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^{\frac{1}{x}}-1}{x^{\alpha}}$$

Now, I know that it doesn't from plotter, but how do I check that by from the expression above? When I checked for which parameters series is convergent I used tests / criteria. But here I have nothing like that. I know that the expression is a variety of a common limit:

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{a^{x}-1}{x} = \ln a$$

But then again, the only value of $\alpha$ for which that would work is $-1$, and we know that $\alpha > 0$. So, my question is, how to prove formaly that there is no such $\alpha$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any $\alpha >0$ the denominator $x^{\alpha}$ of the above fraction goes to 0, whereas the numerator $e^{\frac{1}{x}}-1$ goes to infinity for $x$ going to 0; $x$ positive. So there cannot be any limit.

Comment: That's right. I don't know why I didn't see that myself. Guess I am too much used to limits in $\infty$. Thank you!

Comment: In fact, there is no limit even if $\alpha \le 0$ and fixed; this follows from the fact that for any $e^y >> y^{c}$ for any fixed $c$ and  $y$ large enough.